# Jssor Outer container 'null' not found

Tags: jssor

We have integrated the Jssor banner onto our main page but when you enter the page there is an warning "Outer container 'null' not found". Because of this error the banner is not loading, but when you reload the page the banner works fine. Is there somebody how knows whats causing this problem and how it can be fixed.

The link to the site is: pitstar.com

Thanks in forward.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the following scripts removed all elements in your page.

```
<script>
    // This minimizes flickery of the 1st page load!
    jQuery && jQuery('#main').empty();
</script>
```

Please remove the scripts to get it work.

Comment: I've removed this script but the error is still there. Is there something else that I'm overlooking?

Comment: Please include jquery in your page. <script src="trans_banner/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: Hi Jssor. I indeed forgot to include the jquery file and that's now loaded, but still the same problem. The 1.7.1 is the version the old banner used. If strange thing is dat if you visit an other page and click again to go to the homepage the banner works. Something is still blocking the first page load, but I really can't see what. Hope that you see what I'm missing. Thanks for your help so far.